# Generate random points with kernel density estimate values in R

Tags: r, spatial, kernel-density

I have a data set of thousands of points and 400 polygons and created a kernel density estimate (using the kde2d function) for each polygon based on the points within it. Now I would like to generate 100 random points in each polygon and that each point would have the density value from the kernel estimate.

How can I generate these points?

```
points<- st_read("pbb.shp")
polygons <- st_read("polygon.shp")


for (p in 1:400) {
  poly<- points[points$value == p,]
  kde <- kde2d(poly$X,poly$Y, n=100)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample code isn't reproducible, so I'll create some fake data instead, and use it in my code:

```r
x <- rexp(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
library(MASS)
kde <- kde2d(x, y, n = 100)

size <- 100  # Sample size wanted

# Sample cells from the density matrix
pts <- sample(length(kde$z), size, prob = as.numeric(kde$z))

# Generate the samples by choosing corresponding elements from
# the x and y vectors, and adding some fuzz
xfuzz <- diff(kde$x)[1]/2
sx <- kde$x[row(kde$z)[pts]] + runif(size, -xfuzz, xfuzz)
yfuzz <- diff(kde$y)[1]/2
sy <- kde$y[col(kde$z)[pts]] + runif(size, -yfuzz, yfuzz)

# Plot the original sample and the generated one
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x, y, main = "Real data")
plot(sx, sy, main = "Fake data")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>